# In Firebase Analytics, one of the devices listed is just "iPhone", what does this correspond to?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I see devices like iPhone X, iPhone XR, iPhone XS, then just "iPhone" without any model specifier. Which does this correspond to?

Note it's not an aggregate value of all iPhone models as there's more "iPhone XR" models than there are "iPhone" models.

Comment: "iPhone" only started showing up in our analytics in September 2019. Two things were released that month: iOS 13 and the iPhone 11 range. I suspect it's either an iOS 13 setting where Apple is trying to mask the user's exact device from being tracked, or all three iPhone 11 models are just marked as "iPhone".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and looked up the raw data in big query filtering all events by device.mobile_os_hardware_model where device.mobile_model_name is "iPhone". Result was ~99% iPhone13,4 and ~1% iPhone14,6.

According to following gist they are the internal ids for iPhone 12 Pro Max and iPhone SE 3rd Gen in my case.
https://gist.github.com/adamawolf/3048717

If you want to check on your side, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery and use e.g. following query (users with mobile_model_name = "iPhone" in last 7 days):

```
SELECT
 Value AS Device,
 COUNT(DISTINCT Id) AS Users, 
FROM (
 SELECT
  user_pseudo_id AS Id,
  device.mobile_os_hardware_model as Value
 FROM
  `<your_project>.<your_analytics>.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS params
 WHERE
  SUBSTR(_TABLE_SUFFIX,1, 8) BETWEEN CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AS string)
  AND CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 
  DAY)) AS string)
  AND device.mobile_model_name = "iPhone"
  )
GROUP BY Value
ORDER BY Device DESC
```

[image: Query result]

Comment: Hi there! I am trying to use your approach but I have no prior experience using BigQuery, any documentation that you can think to point me to? Thank you